# $_POST not saving my Select box values

Tags: php, html, post, select

I am in need of a little assistance for a project I am helping with and have hit a small issue with my select boxes in a HTML form. The form is fairly large and has around 60 select boxes however only some of them are showing when i print out the $_POST. Below is the form setup (cut short due to how lengthy it is), the select boxes "DG_Team_Leader" & "DG_Agent" are working fine just the others that do not go through to the $_POST.

```
<form id="Reg_Form" action='/test/' method='POST' style="width: 100%"/> 

<h4>Setup</h4>


<ul>
<Label>Team Leader</label>
<select id="DG_Team_Leader"  name="DG_Team_Leader">

<?php $users = get_users( [ 'role' => 'dg_team_leader_reg' ] );
foreach($users as $rows){

echo "<option value='".$rows->id."'>".$rows->display_name."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</ul>

<ul>
<Label>Agent</label>
<select id="DG_Agent"  name="DG_Agent">

<?php $users = get_users( [ 'role' => 'dg_agent_reg' ] );
foreach($users as $rows){

echo "<option value='".$rows->id."'>".$rows->display_name."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</ul>

<ul style="list-style-type:none">
<Label>Collaborative Working</label>
<select form="Reg_Form" id="DG_Colab" name="DG_Colab">

<?php $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM DG_Colab" );
foreach($myrows as $rows){

echo "<option value='".$rows->id."'>".$rows->Yes_No."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</ul>
<input type='submit' name="submit" value='submit'/>

</form>
```

Any assistance with this would be a great help.

UPDATE:
This is the result of the form when I inspect the page:

```
<table>
<tr><td>DG_Team_Leader</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>DG_Agent</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>DG_Colab</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Conv</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>AHT</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Comments1</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>DG_Area</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>DG_Call_Type</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Call_Date</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Call_Number</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Time_Of_Call</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>DG_Brand</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>DG_Product</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>DG_Question1</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>DG_answer1</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>DG_Question2</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>DG_answer2</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

I cut it short here because it is very long and much of the same.

HTML Rendered Form

```
<h4>Setup</h4>

<ul>
<Label>Team Leader</label>
<select id="DG_Team_Leader"  name="DG_Team_Leader">

<option value='3'>Chris Regan</option></select>
</ul>

<ul>
<Label>Agent</label>
<select id="DG_Agent"  name="DG_Agent">

<option value='4'>John Smith</option></select>
</ul>

<ul style="list-style-type:none">

<Label>Collaborative Working</label>
<select form="Reg_Form" id="DG_Colab" name="DG_Colab">

<option value=''>Yes</option><option value=''>No</option></select>
</ul>

<input type='submit' name="submit" value='submit'/>
```

Cut short after DG_Colab as to match above

Comment: Why does the non-working `select` have a `form="Reg_Form"` attribute?  I've never seen that before, but if it's meaningful then it probably means to attach that element to a specified form.  Try removing that attribute entirely.

Comment: Thanks, it was only added to try and get the select value pushed through to the $_POST. My selects do not work with it or without it sadly.

Comment: well  I for one do not see the use of `$_POST` anywhere, as well as "saving".

Comment: Maybe the browser has closed the form sooner than you expected because of the invalid html. You should only put `li` elements as children of `ul`'s for example.

Comment: I suggest posting the rendered HTML

Comment: Can you show the resulting HTML produced by this PHP code?  What happens when you run it through an HTML validator?  It's possible you have a slightly invalid structure here, resulting in a different DOM than you expect.

Comment: Sure, I can try to show the HTML result.

Comment: The HTML you posted is not a form and does not match the code posted above

Comment: Hi Patrick, the HTML I posted is the results after clicking submit. It goes through to a new page a populates a table with the results from $_POST. It also saves the select values to my DB however all that is blank also.

Comment: For the form you have a self-closing tag and an end tag without a start. That surely doesn't help.

Comment: Hi Marton, just tried to remove close tag and the result is the same. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: This is what I use to populate the table<table>
<?php 
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $key;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $value;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
</table>

Comment: The HTML of the result _after_ you submit is not helpful. What would be helpful is seeing the rendered HTML of the form that you say is not working.

Comment: Okay, I see and agree. I will update the question in a minute. Thanks

Comment: I have added this to the question, I can see that the </form> is missing ... any ideas where it went?

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I can also see the values are missing from the ID field

Comment: If your code is still as above, then the lack of a rendered `form` element is likely due to the self-closing tag, as mentioned by Marton.  Change the end of it from `style="width: 100%"/>` to `style="width: 100%">`.  As for the missing values, if you're not getting any warnings, errors, then I'd say perhaps `id` is actually empty. I'd `var_dump($myrows);exit;` after your `SELECT * FROM DG_Colab` to verify the data you're getting back.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, you have been a huge help. Turns out there is an issue with my ID fields in the DB not an issue with the Select Boxes or $_POST. I also removed the closing tag as suggested by Marton.